# Does member variable still in the buffer when recursion function gets call?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I am trying to understand whether the member variable still in the buffer or not when recursion function gets call each time.

here is my code:

```
 public static int gcd(int m,int n)
{

    System.out.println("Entering 'gcd' method:  m= "+m+",  n="+n);
    if(m%n==0)
    {         
       System.out.println("Returning 'gcd' value ="+n+" (Base case:      m=)"+m+",  n="+n );    
        return n;
    }
    else          
    {

        int temp= gcd(n,m%n);
        System.out.println("Returning 'gcd' value ="+temp+" (recursive case:      m=)"+m+",  n="+n );

        return temp;

    }
```

I don't understand when I enter 843 99 
the System.out.println before return temp. will become reverse print out of M and N

for example:

```
enter two integers(or 'q' to exit):843 99
Entering 'gcd' method:  m= 843,  n=99
Entering 'gcd' method:  m= 99,  n=51
Entering 'gcd' method:  m= 51,  n=48
Entering 'gcd' method:  m= 48,  n=3
Returning 'gcd' value =3 (Base case:      m=)48,  n=3
Returning 'gcd' value =3 (recursive case:      m=)51,  n=48
Returning 'gcd' value =3 (recursive case:      m=)99,  n=51
Returning 'gcd' value =3 (recursive case:      m=)843,  n=99
The GCD of  843 and99 is 3
```

Comment: Just follow the flow

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried step by step to understand. The function stop printing the last statement. Then just print all of the statement backward. I am just confused about the working.

Comment: Think of each recursive method as a wooden block stacked upon each other

Comment: I don't like the term "buffer."  It's a call stack.  And you should think of it exactly that way: "like wooden blocks stacked upon each other."  Each call gets a new block with each of your parameters and local variables written on it.  When the method ends, the block is removed (the memory is reclaimed and reused).  If you Google "hand execution" you'll find links how to work this out by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the state of methods calls are stored on a stack (called the "call stack").

As you may know, a stack is a First In Last Out data structure. This means that If you *push* items A, B, C and D onto the stack in order, the first item you pop from the stack will be D, and the last item you pop would be A.

Whenever you call a method B from a method A, B gets pushed onto the call stack and sits on top of A. B will do its thing and when it returns, it gets popped from the stack and A will carry on with whatever it was doing.

Therefore, the first call to `gcd` will be popped last, and the last call will be popped first, with everything in between being reversed.

This behaviour can be "simulated" using a `java.util.Stack`:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    // simulating calling gcd recursively
    String s = "Call #" + i + " of gcd";
    stack.push(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    // simulating returning from all the calls to gcd
    System.out.print("Returning from ");
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

And it prints:

```
Call #0 of gcd
Call #1 of gcd
Call #2 of gcd
Call #3 of gcd
Call #4 of gcd
Returning from Call #4 of gcd
Returning from Call #3 of gcd
Returning from Call #2 of gcd
Returning from Call #1 of gcd
Returning from Call #0 of gcd
```

Comment: So, even the print out is after the recursion method call, it will release all of them? If in the stack?

Comment: @runable_lame If the print is after the recursive call, then it will be called after that recursive call has been popped from the stack. It _will_ pop all if them, because you have a base case, and your recursive calls are moving towards the base case and will reach it eventually, so the recursive method does not go on forever.

Comment: if i have some process below the recursive call,  then those process will be processing while the recursive call is popping out?

Comment: @runable_lame Not while the recursive call is popping out. The statements after the recursive call will be run _after_ the recursive call is popped (returns). Remember that recursive calls are nothing special. They are just a type of statement, and consecutive statements are executed one after another, not at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

The recursive call, appears one line before printing the output. Therefore, the first output would be the base case and the last output would be the first level of the recursive function. And this is why you get the output in a reversed order.